# Rails Search - Passes params, doesn't return results (error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, query-string

I'm trying to get simple search to work on my Rails app.  I just have two selectors to chose from:  (a) kind and (b) location_id.  The form shows up, values selectable, params pass through in url.  However, nothing shows up when I submit even if there is a something to match it.  I checked in my active admin and there were places to match the search parameters.

This is my **places_controller.rb**

```
def index
   @places = Place.search(params[:kind],[:location_id])
end
```

My **place.rb**

```
def self.search(kind, location_id)
  return scoped unless kind.present? || location_id.present?
  where(['kind = ? AND location_id = ?', kind, location_id])
end
```

and my search form **_home.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag places_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <form class="form-inline text-center" role="form" action="/places">
        <div class="form-group">
           <%= label_tag :kind %>
           <%= select_tag :kind, options_for_select([['beer','0'],['chocolate','1'],['cocktail','2'], ['coffee','3'], ['tea','4'], ['wine','5'], ['juice','6']]), class: "form-control" %>
         /div>
 <br>
         <div class="form-group">
            <%= label_tag :location_id %><br>
            <%= select_tag :location_id, options_for_select([['Houston','0'],['San Francisco','1'],['Santiago','2'], ['Valparaiso','3'], ['Rio de Janeiro','4'], ['Milan','5'], ['Palo Alto','6'], ['Las Vegas','7'], ['New York','8'], ['San Diego','9']]), class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
 <br>
 <br>
          <div class="actions">
          <span itemprop="significantLink">
          <%= submit_tag 'Search', :name => nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
          </span>
          </div>
 </form>
 <% end %>
```

Would appreciate any help!  Have looked around on a bunch of SO/Railscasts and not sure what to do!

Comment: Where in your code to you use the `@places` variable you set to the search results?

Comment: in my index.html.erb /places                                               <% @places.each do |place| %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I see something wrong. Define index as this:

```
def index
   @places = Place.search(params[:kind], params[:location_id])
end
```

Also, You might want to actually use a respond_to block to negotiate what the response should be such as html or json.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { YOUR STUFF HERE }
  format.json { YOUR STUFF HERE }
end
```

My best recommendation would be to put a `debugger` statement after the @places assignment so that you can actually debug what is going on and see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  Do you mean something like this?  I'm very new to coding, so a bit confused.    def index
      @ places = Place.search(params[:kind], params[:location_id])

      respond_to do |format|
        if @ place.search
          format.html {redirect_to @ places}
          format.json {redirect_to @ places}
        else
          format.html {redirect_to @ places.all}
          format.json {redirect_to @ places.all}
        end
      end 
  end
I put spaces after the @'s for SO

Comment: First of all. When you are reading parameters passed from the view you need to always use params[:VALUE]. Values are always passed from the form as a hash back to the controller. Doesn't matter if it is a GET, POST, PUT, Form or Querystring.